# How to do a Marionette catchall route?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I need a catchall route in Marionette.

For example, I have users `jane` `bob` `alice`, and I want them to be able to access their profiles with:

```
http://example.com/#jane
http://example.com/#bob
http://example.com/#alice
```

However, if I want to single out a route, `#edit` to go somewhere else, for example, their edit page.

Is there a way to do this in Backbone/Marionette?

Comment: did the below help at all?

Comment: ill let you know soon. im about to implement it... got stuck on some refactoring!!

Answer (score 1):

So you can do this using the normal routes but the order in which they are declared becomes important which sucks a bit

```
appRoutes: {
    "some_part_of_app/edit": "showEditPage",
    "some_part_of_app/:username": "showProfilePage",
}
```

in this way it will try to match the route against edit first then when it fails it will then match against the next route, if these were the other way round it would always match the /:username route.

But if i was doing something like this i would make the routes a bit more descriptive and avoid this issue altogether

```
appRoutes: {
    "some_part_of_app/profile/:username/edit": "showEditPage",
    "some_part_of_app/profile/:username": "showProfilePage",
}
```

in this way its clear from the route which resource is be being acted upon and you don;t have to rely on the order of declaration to get around the catch all situation.

or the other option is to to use a plugin like https://github.com/boazsender/backbone.routefilter which would allow you to pre filter the route and ensure edit went to the edit route and :usernames went to the users names.